# Google App Script Authorization fails when using UrlFetchApp and DocumentApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, urlfetch

I'm trying to write an Add-On for Google Docs. It worked fine when only using DriveApp and MailApp, but as soon as I tried using UrlFetchApp, it stopped working. What happens is that I get an OAuth dialog pop up saying:

> [App] needs your permission to access your data on Google

When I click "Review Permissions" and choose my Google account, I then get taken to the google 500 error page with no useful information.

> There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.

My project properties shows these scopes:

5 OAuth Scopes required by the script:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
```

This script reproduces the problem:

```
function reproduceError() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com"); 
}
```

When I remove the UrlFetchApp statement from my script, the prompt to authorize the app goes away, and everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue on Google's side.
I have the same on my scripts using UrlFetchApp.
We can only report the error and wait.

Comment: Thanks for confirming you have the issue as well. It seems to have started working now, minutes after I logged the bug with Google.